# Detect rotation of subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a view containing several subviews. I can detect and let the user rotate just one subview or the containing view using UIRotationGestureRecognizer. But I would like to be able to rotate any square collection of subviews, like so:

Initial state:

[image: Initial state]

Rotating upper right square counter-clockwise

[image: Rotating upper right square]

To get here

[image: To get here]

How can I achieve this behavior?
How should I nest my view hierarchy?

Any pointers are appreciated :)

Comment: If you can rotate *any* square collection of squares... I don't think there's a single view hierarchy that will work. You will have to do more complicated things, i.e. when rotation is in progress, apply the appropriate transform to each tile in the rotated collection... and when rotation completes, reorder the tiles in your array as appropriate. so: one view/layer per tile is what I propose.

Comment: it might be a little easier to move the tiles being rotated into a temporary transparent parent layer to which you apply rotation, and then move them back to the correct places in the original view after rotation.

Answer (score 0):

here's what I would do (pseudocode):

```
when rotation recognized:
    create new_layer
    new_layer.bounds = union_rect( frames of tiles to be rotated )
    new_layer addSublayers:(tiles to be rotated)

while rotation in progress:
    new_layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation( angle, 0, 0, 1 )

when rotation complete:
    (original view).layer addSublayers:(tiles to be rotated)
    (tiles to be rotated) rearrange after rotation
```